# checking class in c++ templates without class instance

Tags: c++, templates, rtti

I need to write template which generates some code depending on whether template parameter is instance of of some class. The template can be generated for all classes but only in case the class is subclass of other class the code should be executed.

The problem is that function that should be implemented does not receive any instance of the class, so the only thing known is class name. So it is impossible to achieve this with dynamic_cast as it demands instance of the object

```
template<T>
class A 
{
  void somefunction(void)
  {
     if (T instanceof Foo) then ...
     else ...
  }
}
```

adding some explanation

```
class X: public Foo {};
class Y {};

class A<X> {} // special logic is generated
class A<Y> {} // special logic is NOT generated
```

Comment: If you need a special behaviour for Foo instances in a Template, I think you don't need a Template class, you need a Template Method pattern...

Comment: @Miguel Angel: He only **needs** it if he needs runtime polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use template specialization or boost::is_base_of from the [boost traits library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/is_base_of.html)
Or of course write your own traits, but shouldn't, for you have not mastered templates yet.

Using specialization, you could

```
template<T>
class A 
{
  void somefunction() {
     // generic version
  }
};
template<>
class A <Foo>
{
  void somefunction() {
     // foo version
  }
};
```

As always, let me recommend Vandevoorde/Josuttis "C++ Templates: The Complete Guide".

If you fear code bloat because only one memberfunction out of many needs to be specialized, you can still outsource that function:

```
template <typename T> struct somefunction_helper {
    static void thatfunction () {
        // generic form
    }
};
template <> struct somefunction_helper<Foo> {
    static void thatfunction () {
        // Foo form
    }
};

template<T>
class A 
{
  void somefunction()  {
     somefunction_helper<T>::thatfunction();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what template specializations are for. They're more difficult to write, but that's what you do with them. For example:

```
template<T> class A
{
    void somefunction(void) {
        ...//default for any object type.
    }
};

template<> class A<Foo>
{
    void somefunction(void) {
        ...//specific to the type Foo.
    }
};
```

Yes, it requires an extra bit of work. There are some template metaprogramming ways to do this the way you want, but someone else will have to explain those.

Comment: Foo is only base class the template never instantiated with it as a parameter

Comment: @Boris: Your comment makes no sense. If `A` is never instantiated, then your member function would never be called. _If_ `A` is actually used, there _will_ be an actual parameter for `T` and this will work. (Note that neither Nicol's nor my solution requires an object of type `T` to be instantiated.)

Comment: class X: Foo {}, class Y{} , The A instantiated only with X and Y as parameters but not Foo itself ( A<X> and A <Y>) - for class X the special logic should be called.

Answer (score 1):

Either specialize `A` or delegate the work of the `someFunction()` member function template to some free function template which you can (fully) specializes on `T`.

Comment: same comment as above - Foo is only base class the template never instantiated with it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Since specialization won't work since the template parameter will only ever be derived from `Foo`, use what another answer said: `is_base_of`, either from Boost or from the standard library if it already supports parts of C++0x:

```
#include <type_traits> // C++0x

class Foo{};

template<class T>
class A{
  void specialOnFoo(){
    // dispatch the call
    specialOnFoo(std::is_base_of<T, Foo>::type());
  }

  void specialOnFoo(std::true_type){
    // handle Foo case
  }

  void specialOnFoo(std::false_type){
    // non-Foo case
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit #2 - see working example.** Please note that this the run-time equivalent of template specialization (which happens at compile-time) and requires RTTI enabled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

class Foo {};
class X: public Foo {};
class Y {};

template<typename T> class A {
public:
  void somefunction()
  {
    if (typeid(T) == typeid(X)) {
      cout << "X specific logic happening" << endl;
    }
    else {
      cout << "Default behavior" << endl;
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  A<X> ax;
  A<Y> ay;
  ax.somefunction(); // prints "X specific logic happening"
  ay.somefunction(); // prints "Default behavior"
}
```

---

`typeid` can be used with templates to extract the type of the template parameter -- as described below:

```
// expre_typeid_Operator_3.cpp
// compile with: /c
#include <typeinfo>
template < typename T > 
T max( T arg1, T arg2 ) {
   cout << typeid( T ).name() << "s compared." << endl;
   return ( arg1 > arg2 ? arg1 : arg2 );
}
```

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyf39xec(v=vs.80).aspx

**Note that the value of `name()` is implementation defined.**

Comment: the return value of `name()` is implementation defined and one shall not rely on its content.

Comment: Ok -- I am updating the answer to include note on the portability of `name()`

Comment: And how exactly can this be applied to solve the problem at hand??